# FHE modular reduction in specific range

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to implement a naive version of CKKS in Python.
It was great until I start implementing the modulus.

For this kind of schemes, the modulus $q$ is in the range $(-q/2,q/2]$.
How does this work?

In CKKS paper (I think BGV and others do the same) use something like this (a toy example): $c = m (mod$ $q)$. Where $c$ and $m$ are polynomials, so the coefficients of m are mod q. So c and m are congruent mod q.

So for each coefficient $n$ (if the range of mod is the typical $[0,1,...q-1]$), a way is to solve:

$n = m*q + R$

Where $m$ is the greatest integer that makes $n<m*q$ and $R$ is the remainder that solves the equation being this the same reminder that for c,  so n is the result for the coefficient.

But if the modulus range is other like I say, how is this done?
The intuition says me that is like wrapping the number in a ''clock''
that starts in -q/2+1 and goes up to q/2 before starting again.
But I don't know how to apply this intuition for negative numbers that are smaller than -q/2.

For example which is the answer of
**-771 (mod 1280)**

Answer (score -1):

If you first have some modulus function $x\bmod q$ that *always* returns a value in $[0, q)$, it is straightforward to switch this to your desired modulus function, for example one can define

$$x\bmod^{\pm} q := (x\bmod q) - \lfloor q/2\rfloor.$$

This is to say that to get a modulus function that returns a value in $[c, c+q)$ rather than $[0,q)$, it suffices to (manually) shift the result of calling the standard modulus function.

Comment: This was my first attempt and didn't work.... So I have a bug in other please!
At least I know that the mod was not the problem.

Comment: For some programming languages there is a difference between "modulus" and "remainder", usually with how they treat negative inputs. I would try to look into the documentation of your programming language for this, as it is likely the issue.

Comment: Thats true. I think that Python %, implementes modulus, so thats its correct.
Tell me if what I think its correct.
The idea of  this congruence in the new interval its that $c\equiv x\pmod q$, its to find witch $c \in (-q/2, q/2]$ has the same modulus that $m \bmod q$?
For what I understand $q/2\bmod q=q/2$, but if at that I subtract $q/2$ will give me  a wrong answer (for what I understand).
What I'm missing?

Comment: If your issue is one of the rounding boundary, i.e. $(-q/2, q/2]$ vs $[-q/2, q/2)$, you could simply add/subtract 1 from the result as necessary.

Comment: @mmazz: one way to implement $c \in (-q/2, q/2]$ (given a % operation that gives a result in $[0, q)$ is $c = ((x + (q/2-1)) \% q) - (q/2-1)$

Comment: @poncho: Your formula is off-by-one for odd integer $q>0$ in most languages where `q/2` in an integer. E.g. in C, for `int q=5, x=3, c=((x+(q/2-1))%q)-(q/2-1);` we get `c==3`. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44rM69EITcxM0@jLD8zRVOhmosTJFJoa6qjUGFrrKOQbKuhUaGtUahvpGuoqalaqKkLZVtzcRYUAdWmaSippijpJIMEilJLSovyFAysuWr//wcA). Consider making an answer, because **the [current answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/102859/1) is wrong.**